# Python Kivy: Refer to Label(Button) id (created in *.py file) via self.ids command

Tags: python, django, kivy

I am working with two files

- test.py
- test.kv

The content of test.py is the following:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file("test.kv")


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def printIds(self):
        print self.ids

    def printChildren(self):
        print self.ids.box.children
        for child in self.ids.box.children:
            print child.text, child.id

    def addButton(self):
        self.ids.box.add_widget(Button(text = "newly added Button", id = "test_button_id"))

    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
         super(MyApp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def build(self):
        app = MainScreen()
        return app



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The content of test.kv is:

```
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        id: box 
        Label:
            text: "test label"
            id: test_label_id
        Button:
            text: "Print Children"
            on_release: root.printChildren()
        Button:
            text: "Print ids"
            on_release: root.printIds()
        Button:
            text: "Add Button"
            on_release: root.addButton()
```

My problem is the following:
I want to access the newly added Button (which will be added when calling the function addButton via pressing the Button Add Button) via the self.ids command in the python file. But when i do so (i.e. pressing the Button Print ids) it only shows the ids which i have assigned in the kivy file, namely: box (which is the id of the BoxLayout) and test_label_id (which is the id of the test label).

Am I thinking wrong? I mean if I add a Button in the python file with the `self.ids.box.add_widged(Button(text="...", id="..."))` command it should be visible via the `self.ids` command, right?

I can also test this in somehow the other direction: If I print all the children of the `boxlayout` and grab their e.g. text and id with the command `child.text` or `child.id` it displays me the text and id of the newly added button and also the text of the other Buttons/Labels but not the ids which I have assigned in the kivy file (in particular: it displays None for them).

Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**ID** is created only in **kv** lang and such an action (`Button(id='something')`) isn't usable in the way a common:

```
Button:
    id: my_id
```

would be. It doesn't store ids in a parent's `ids` dictionary. However, you might be able to modify the parent's `ids` dictionary with some neat trick (it's only an "observable" dictionary), but in the end you'd need to make the reference to your widget a *weak*/proxy one, otherwise the widget wouldn't be garbage-collected.

A better idea is to either create some container for your widgets in kv and just use its `children` property with an index, or make a custom property together with looping through its parent children and checking for the value of the custom property, or something like this:

```
# in App class
class X(App):
    my_widgets = DictProperty()

# in custom widget init
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(<class name>, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    app = App.get_running_app()
    app.my_widgets['my_new_widget'] = WeakProxy(Button())
```

Ref [`WeakProxy`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.weakproxy.html). :)

Comment: thanks for your fast answer! I tried to adapt my code to include the dictionary as you suggested, but I get  the following error when executing:


TypeError: 'kivy.properties.DictProperty' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @klexx oh, riiight, move the `DictProperty` to the class level (remove `self.` and under `class MyApp...`), then it should work. Bad mistake, sorry ^^ Check the edit.

Comment: ok it compiles now. thanks again :)
I try to figure out if I can solve my problem with this. I'll probably come back on this ... :)